# Direct upgrade to elementary OS 6

Tags: system-installation

will the devs introduce a way to directly upgrade Elementary OS from one version to another when Elementary OS 6 releases?

Answer (score 0):

Can we have an official answer here please ?

I was also looking for this and I couldn't find anything related to it.

So, would it be possible to upgrade from 5.1 to 6 once it is out ?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same question you are asking, and to solve it, I made a discussion here on StackExchange and on Elementary OS' GitHub Page and also created a issue of it.

Please visit the following links

[How to update from Elementary OS 5.1.7 to Elementary 6](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28515/how-to-update-from-elementary-os-5-1-7-to-elementary-6)

Many people told me it is not officially possible till now.

https://github.com/elementary/os/discussions/535

GitHub Discussion: There also all I got was disappointment.

https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/538

GitHub Issue: Status: Closed (Duplicate)

It was linked to this older accepted issue: https://github.com/elementary/triage/issues/46

Thanks & Regards
Animish Yadav

P.S. Sorry for disappointment.

Comment: You can say Developers are not working on it.