# How to update from Elementary OS 5.1.7 to Elementary 6

Tags: updates, release-odin

have a device of configuration: i3, 4GB RAM, 1TB HDD, Dual Booted to Windows 10 and Elementary 5.1.7 with 125 GB for Elementary OS.

The sole reason to have Dual Boot on such weak and old device was that it was becoming difficult for the device to handle Windows 10 with a web-browser and a video conferencing app together and work without hanging for hours. So to ease my day to day work, I switched to Elementary OS, with no knowledge of Linux at all. I just knew how to make an ISO file to boot able media and install it.

So I have been using it for months, and now I wish to update to Elementary OS 6, so my basic question is how to update to V6 from V5.1.7 without opting for a fresh/clean start, losing all apps and data. I checked the official website it says nothing for those who already are on the OS, and in the System Settings app, it shows no components is available to update.

Please note I am a 15 year old student with least knowledge of Linux, so please explain all steps, all commands you may refer to. I know it may be a lot extra effort to explain in such manner, and it would really nice of all of you guys to help me out.

Thanks & Regards,
Animish Yadav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this https://github.com/meisenzahl/upgrade
you will need to build it from source instructions in the repo's readme

Comment: Thanks.

But what about articles which say we can switch Linux Distros with the help of knowledge of partitioning [I have no knowledge of it though.] .

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/upgrade-switch-linux-distros-without-losing-files/

Comment: @AnimishYadav This would have been possible but hard if they were based on the same ubuntu version and have same repos

Comment: You can we do it for 5.1.7 of Elementary to 6.0 of Elementary?

Comment: @AnimishYadav I edited the question try it

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I was stuck in a desperate situation where  I had to update it ASAP, so I actually just backed up stuff and installed it clean.

Thanks for your time and help, I guess it would help others with the process.

Comment: Also, you can help another person who is looking for solution to exact similar problem!

Here: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28514/upgrade-latest-hera-to-odin

Answer (score -1):

That is, Abdallah Mohammad the creators of elementary.io are deceiving us, because in at least 3 publications I have read that it is possible to upgrade from 5.1.7 Hera to 6.0 Odin from the application center. So, the question is how to allow us to update because it doesn't give me the option to do so yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, as far as I have noticed, there is a check for update button in System Settings app which does nothing and takes us to app centre so I guess if they roll out this feature it will from there only.

And After seeing this update situation, I guess Elementary OS is not a replacement to Windows and MacOS. I know we all hate Windows Updates, but at least they showed the update and offered far better method that fresh installation.